# Proof of $\text{sgn}(\sigma \cdot \tau)=\text{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \text{sgn}(\tau)$ in Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, proof-explanation, determinant

> From the point of view of products of permutations, the basic property of the sign of a permutation is that $\text{sgn}(\sigma \cdot \tau)=\text{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \text{sgn}(\tau)$. In other words, $\sigma\cdot \tau$ is an even permutation if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are either both even or both odd, while $\sigma \cdot \tau$ is odd if one of the two permutations is odd and the other is even. One can see this from the definition of the sign in terms of successive interchanges of pairs $(i, j)$.

In last sentence, Hoffman’s claim we can prove $\text{sgn}(\sigma \cdot \tau)=\text{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \text{sgn}(\tau)$ from definition of sgn in terms of successive interchanges of pairs, i.e. $\text{sgn}:S_n \to K$ such that $\text{sgn}(\sigma)=1_K$, if $(\sigma (1),…,\sigma (n))$ is obtained from $(1,2,…,n)$ by even number of interchanges of pairs, and $\text{sgn}(\sigma)=-1_K$, if $(\sigma (1),…,\sigma (n))$ is obtained from $(1,2,…,n)$ by odd number of interchanges of pairs. **Que:** I don’t really see if $(\sigma \circ \tau(1),…,\sigma \circ \tau(n))$ is obtained from $(1,…,n)$ by even or odd number of interchanges of pair. IMO, composition makes things bit complicated. There must be some intermediate argument to convince why $\text{sgn}(\sigma \cdot \tau)=\text{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \text{sgn}(\tau)$ is true using definition of sgn in terms of interchanges of pairs.

Hoffman’s then showed $\text{sgn}(\sigma \cdot \tau)=\text{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \text{sgn}(\tau)$ from elementary property of determinant.

> Let $\sigma ,\tau \in S_n$. Let $A=(e_{\tau (1)},…,e_{\tau (n)})$ and $B=(e_{\sigma (1)},…,e_{\sigma (n)})$. Then $\text{det}(A)=\sum_{\mu\in S_n}\text{sgn}(\mu)\prod_{i=1}^nA(i,\mu (i))$. If $\mu \neq \tau$, then $\exists j\in J_n$ such that $\mu (j)\neq \tau (j)$. So $A(j,\mu (j))=0$. Thus $\text{sgn}(\mu)\prod_{i=1}^nA(i,\mu (i))=0$, $\forall \mu \in S_n \setminus\{\tau\}$. Hence $\text{det}(A)=\text{sgn}(\tau)\prod_{i=1}^nA(i,\tau (i))=\text{sgn}(\tau)$. Similarly, $\text{det}(B)=\text{sgn}(\sigma)$. It’s easy to see $AB=(e_{\sigma \cdot \tau(1)},…,e_{\sigma \cdot \tau (n)})$. So $\text{det}(AB)=\text{sgn}(\sigma \cdot \tau)$. Since $\text{det}(AB)= \text{det}(A)\cdot \text{det}(B)$, we have $\text{sgn}(\sigma \cdot \tau)=\text{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \text{sgn}(\tau)$.

**Que:** How to rigioursly show $AB=(e_{\sigma \cdot \tau(1)},…,e_{\sigma \cdot \tau (n)})$? I known $AB=(e_{\tau(1)},…,e_{\tau (n)})\cdot B=(e_{\tau (1)}\cdot B,…,e_{\tau (n)}\cdot B)$, by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4542368/861687) post.

**Edit:** $P_\sigma =B^t$ and $P\tau =A^t$. It’s easy to check, if $R,S\in M_{n\times n}(K)$, then $(R\cdot S)^t=S^t\cdot R^t$. So $P_{\sigma \tau}= P_{\sigma}\cdot P_{\tau}=B^t\cdot A^t=(A\cdot B)^t$. Thus $A\cdot B=(P_{\sigma \tau})^t=(e_{\sigma \cdot \tau(1)},…,e_{\sigma \cdot \tau (n)})$.

Comment: Could you detail what $A,B$ are?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yess. $A,B\in M_n(K)$ with $e_{\tau (1)},…,e_{\tau (n)}$ and $e_{\sigma(1)},…,e_{\sigma (n)}$ rows, respectively, where $e_i=(a_1,…,a_n)$ such that $a_i=1$ and $a_j=0$, $\forall j\in J_n-\{i\}$.

Comment: Consider the polynomial $\prod (x_k-x_j)A$ with $k > j$ and for all $k,j \leq n$. Now consider how the permutation action changes that polynomial to establish there is a homomorphism from $S_n$ to $\{1,-1\}$ under multiplication.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I’m sorry to say, your solution is more difficult than Hoffman’s.

Comment: @user264745 it's actually not that hard. Because $k > j$ each term $(x_k-x_j)$ encodes exactly one transposition. It's also easy to see that $x_j-x_k=-(x_k-x_j)$. But, now we're done since we're just sign switching on the polynomial. That's the group $\{1,-1\}$ under multiplication and we have the homomorphism we desired.

Comment: @user264745 Strange that it is rows and not columns.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net We can work with columns instead of rows. I think result will not get affected.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net This definition ensures $\sigma\mapsto P_\sigma$ is a homomorphism and $S_n\curvearrowright\Bbb K^n$ is a left action. The other convention, using standard basis row vectors, creates an antihomomorphism and a right action of $S_n$ (but written on the left by applying matrices from the left to columns). If we view a vector $(x_i)$ as a function $i\mapsto x_i$, the former is the "contragredient" action and trips many people up. It is also why $f(x+1)$ for example moves the graph of $y=f(x)$ to the left instead of the right (and similarly for $f(2x)$ shrinking a graph).

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Que#:~:text=One%20of%20our%20persistent%E2%80%94and,up%20que%20in%20our%20dictionary.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Why did you delete your answer? Is it because it was wrong?

Comment: Because it was already contained in my answer which was posted 10min earlier (and also mixed up which of $A$ or $B$ went to $\sigma$ or $\tau$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if we define $\mathrm{sgn}$ to be $\pm1$ according to the parity of the number of transpositions used to create the permutation, the hard part is showing the sign is even well-defined to begin with (since the number of transpositions is not unique), after which showing it is a homomorphism is easy.

This is because if $\sigma=\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_k$ is a product of $k$ transpositions and $\tau=\tau_1\cdots\tau_\ell$ a product of $\ell$ transpositions, then $\sigma\tau=\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_k\tau_1\cdots\tau_\ell$ is a product of $k+\ell$ transpositions, so the homomorphism property  $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma\tau)=\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\mathrm{sgn}(\tau)$ simply reads $(-1)^{k+\ell}=(-1)^k(-1)^\ell$.

Let $P_\sigma=(e_{\sigma(1)}~\cdots~e_{\sigma(n)})$ be the permutation matrix associated to a permutation $\sigma$. Then $P_\sigma$ is characterized by the property $P_\sigma e_j=e_{\sigma(j)}$, by definition of matrix multiplication. This means we can simply read off $P_\sigma P_\tau e_j=P_\sigma e_{\tau(j)}=e_{\sigma(\tau(j))}$ to conclude $P_\sigma P_\tau=P_{\sigma\tau}$.

Or, we can define $P_\sigma=[\delta_{i\sigma(j)}]$ using the Kronecker delta symbol, then calculate $$P_\sigma P_\tau=[\delta_{i\sigma(j)}][\delta_{j\tau(k)}]=\Big[\sum_j \delta_{i\sigma(j)}\delta_{j\tau(k)}\Big]=[\delta_{i\sigma(\tau(k))}]=P_{\sigma\tau}.$$

Note after matrix multiplication we can erase all zero summands (i.e. all but when $j=\tau(k)$).

Comment: I will take some time to completely absorb your answer and ask you some que. First paragraph: “hard part is showing the sign is even well-defined to begin with” in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4547371/861687) post I showed sgn maps to a unique point in $\{1_K,-1_K\}$ using contradiction, i.e. number of interchanges is always even or always odd. Are you taking about group homomorphism? Because we’re looking for $f(u\cdot v)=f(u)\cdot f(v)$ property, preserve group structure. We haven’t yet shown sgn is homomorphism.

Comment: I don't think it's obvious that the parity in the number of transpositions used to construct a permutation is invariant. If you define the determinant (which is unique), the sign of a permutation is easily seen to be well-defined as it is the determinant of the permutation matrix, but this requires linear algebra for a combinatorial question, so I still wouldn't call it obvious. As for the second part of my answer, your $AB=(e_{\sigma\tau})$ claim is just $P_\sigma P_\tau=P_{\sigma\tau}\,$, which says $\sigma\mapsto P_\sigma$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: I agree, we used notion of determinant to prove sgn is well defined. **Second paragraph:** I don’t known proof of “every $\sigma \in S_n$ may be factored in a product of adjacent transposition” because Hoffman didn’t took this approach. First time I saw that claim in [this](https://youtu.be/3BaZ3SkTfc0) video (time stamp 10:24). It’s proof is not straightforward. I don’t understand following statement, “so the homomorphism property $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma\tau)=\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\mathrm{sgn}(\tau)$ simply reads $(-1)^{k+\ell}=(-1)^k(-1)^\ell$“.

Comment: **Third  paragraph:** For future reader I’m completing details of $P_\sigma e_j=e_{\sigma(j)}$ result. $(P_\sigma\cdot e_j)_{i1}=\sum_k (P_\sigma)_{ik}\cdot (e_j)_{k1}=\sum_k \delta_{i\sigma (k)}\delta_{kj}$. So $\delta_{i\sigma (k)}\delta_{kj}\neq 0$, if $i=\sigma (k)$ and $j=k$. Which implies $\sigma (j)=\sigma (k)=i$ and $j=k$. Thus $(P_\sigma e_j)_{i1}=0$, $\forall i\neq \sigma (j)$ and $(P_\sigma e_j)_{\sigma (j)1}=\delta_{\sigma (j)\sigma (j)}\delta_{jj}=1$. Hence $P_\sigma e_j=e_{\sigma (j)}$.

Comment: $(P_\sigma P_{\tau})(e_j)=e_{\sigma \tau (j)}=P_{\sigma \tau}(e_j)$, $\forall j\in J_n$ implies $P_\sigma P_\tau=P_{\sigma \tau}$, because if $A\in M_n(F)$, then $A\cdot e_j$ is $j$th column of $A$. **Fourth paragraph:** $\delta_{i\sigma(j)}\delta_{j\tau(k)}\neq 0$, if $i=\sigma (j)$ and $\tau (k)=j$. Which implies $\sigma (\tau (k))=\sigma (j)=i$ and $j=\tau (k)$. Hence $\sum_j \delta_{i\sigma(j)}\delta_{j\tau(k)}=\delta_{i \sigma (\tau (k))}$.

Comment: **2nd para**: If you know $\sigma\tau$ is a product of $k+\ell$ transpositions, then you know ${\rm sgn}(\sigma\tau)$ is $(-1)^{k+\ell}$, and similarly with ${\rm sgn}(\sigma)$ and ${\rm sgn}(\tau)$. So ${\rm sgn}(\sigma\tau)={\rm sgn}(\sigma){\rm sgn}(\tau)$ is equivalent to $(-1)^{k+\ell}=(-1)^k(-1)^\ell$, just replace each sign with the power of $(-1)$ it is equal to. **3rd para**, $P_\sigma e_j=e_{\sigma(j)}$ because $P_\sigma e_j$ is the $j$th column of $P_\sigma$ which we've defined to be $e_{\sigma(j)}$, don't need to overcomplicate it. **4th para**: and the summand $=0$ otherwise, yes.

Comment: Yup $\text{sgn}(\sigma \tau)= \text{sgn}(\sigma) \text{sgn}(\tau)$ is equivalent to $(-1)^{k+l}=(-1)^k(-1)^l$. But showing existence of $\sigma =\sigma_1\dotsb \sigma_k$ is not trivial. One need a different framework (compared to Hoffman’s) of parity of permutation. In 3rd para, I showed $j$th column of $P_\sigma P_\tau$ is equal to $j$th column of $P_{\sigma \tau}$. Which implies $P_\sigma P_\tau = P_{\sigma \tau}$. I don’t think, I over complicated it.

Comment: Yess… I over complicated it. I’m so stupid. It’s easy to check, if $A\in M_{n\times n}(K)$, then $A\cdot e_j$ is $j$th column of matrix $A$. So $P_\sigma \cdot e_j$ denotes $j$th column of $P_\sigma$. As you said “which we've defined to be $e_{\sigma (j)}$”. I unnecessary reproved $P_\sigma \cdot e_j=e_{\sigma (j)}$.